# What is right way to initialize nested entities?

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext

Eclipse with plugin for DSL with following grammar (xtext)

```
AbstractStatement returns AbstractStatement:
    IfStructureStatement | DeclarativeStatement | BreakStatement | EqualityStatement | SignalStatement;

Component returns Component:
    LED_Panel | Switch | Timer | LED_Light;

Setup returns Setup:
    {Setup}
    'SETUP BEGIN'
        ( abstractstatement+=AbstractStatement ( "\r" abstractstatement+=AbstractStatement)* )?
    'SETUP END';

DeclarativeStatement returns DeclarativeStatement:
    {DeclarativeStatement}
    'DECLARE'
    ( component+=[Component|EString] ( "," component+=[Component|EString])* )?
    ( variable+=[Variable|EString] ( "," variable+=[Variable|EString])* )?
    ( constant+=[Constant|EString] ( "," constant+=[Constant|EString])* )?";";

LED_Panel returns LED_Panel:
    {LED_Panel}
    'LED_PANEL'
    ElementName=EString
    ('{'
        'PanelWidth' PanelWidth=EInt
        'PanelHeight' PanelHeight=EInt
        'PanelText' PanelText=EString
        'ON' '{' pin+=Pin ( "," pin+=Pin)* '}' 
    '}')?;
```

And the following source file:

```
SETUP BEGIN
DECLARE LED_PANEL p;
SETUP END
```

This code gives me error "missmatched input LED_PANEL", expecting ";"
It is acting like he can not recognize Component LED_PANEL

I expect that he can validate this code.

Comment: On which input do you get that error? Also is this your entire grammar? If `AbstractStatement` is your start rule (which would be strange as source files usually consist of more than one statement), it doesn't look like you allow components to appear anywhere. Also note that `DeclarativeStatement`'s definition is highly ambiguous.

Comment: SETUP BEGIN
DECLARE LED_PANEL p;
SETUP END

This is input. This is not entire grammar, there is root concept which contains multiple AbstractStatement instances. DeclarativeStatement is concretization of AbstractStatement class and in this class I have multiple Component instances. LED_Panel is concretization of Component abstract class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that you had already included the source at the end of the grammar. Anyway, `DECLARE LED_PANEL p;` doesn't look like valid syntax according to your grammar. `DECLARE` should be followed by an `EString` (whatever that is exactly - usually `EString`'s a type, not a token) or a semicolon.

Comment: Why? component+=[Component|EString] Does this mean that after "DECLARE" I can have either Component or EString? And if not, how to do that? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DeclarativeStatement` rule you have `component+=[Component|EString]`. This means "match an `EString` token; that token should be the name of a `Component` (meaning an instance of the `Component` class)". As far as the parser is concerned, that's equivalent to `component+=EString` - the fact that it's a cross reference only comes into play once we get to the linker.

It does not mean "match a `Component`". If that's what you want, you should just write `component+=Component` (or even better `components+=Component` since lists should have plural names).

Cross references are intended for situations where you expect the *name* of something defined elsewhere. If you expect the whole thing, there should be no cross reference.